# Using YouTube V3.0/V2.0 API to download JSON feed of channel stats and videos

Tags: json, api, youtube-api

I am trying to use a YouTube V3.0 API call to download a JSON feed of information for a particular YouTube channel (e.g: the Apple YouTube channel).

I have been looking at the YouTube API documentation, however I am struggling to construct the correct URL that I need to make the API call.

Basically, I just want this API call to return a JSON feed containing information such a the amount of subscribers, the amount of total video views for a particular YouTube channel.

Any help would be great, thanks.
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Channels->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) call id what you re looking for. You can use the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#try-it) at the end of the page to customize your search and construct the GET request you need.